# Object not found! in xampp

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, laravel-4

I'm using creo's module system and laravel 4. mod_rewrite is enabled and I have a .htaccess I'm also using XAMPP. The weird thing is, if I use MAMP then it works fine but if I use XAMPP that is when I get the Object Not Found error. I would like to use XAMPP because it is much more easier to create a virtual host with it then it is with MAMP.

In my url I have

> http://localhost/test-modules/index.php/admin/content

but I need it to be

> http://localhost/test-modules/admin/content

here is my .htaccess

```
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On


# Redirect Trailing Slashes...
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

# Disallow access to following directories
#RewriteRule ^vendor($|/|/.*|./*) – [L,R=404]
#RewriteRule ^app($|/|/*|/.*) – [L,R=404]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do yourself a favor and don't use either MAMP or XAMP. Use homestead.
http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/homestead

To give you some guides:

https://laracasts.com/lessons/say-hello-to-laravel-homestead-two